# Show Inner Test results of a Generic Test in summary

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, generic-test

I have a little problem with generic test and building project using TFS. I have a Silverlight user control, which I am testing using Silverlight unit tests from toolkit. Also we have a build machine, and using StatLight, I managed to make run test automatically when project is building(thanks to author of this article http://www.nielshebling.de/?p=167). 
The problem is in results, I would like that inner test results were shown in summary(look at the screenshot below). Now it's showing that only one test was run(the generic test). http://img705.imageshack.us/i/screenqqs.jpg/

Is it even possible? 
Using XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe) I generated a class from SummaryResult.xsd. Maybe it's possible to rewrite this class so the results of inner test were shown in Summary?
Your help would be greatly appreciated

P.S. excuse me for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these two articles:

- [Summary results file for VSTS Generic Tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2005/12/07/summary-results-file-in-vsts.aspx) (the example is coded in VB but it is easy to follow. It helped me much.)
- [Manual, Generic, and Ordered Tests](http://www.packtpub.com/article/manual-generic-ordered-test-using-visual-studio-2008) (in the last part of this article a generic test is described. There are some useful screen shots so you can decide if it is worth for you implementing it, meaning if the information provided by *Summary Result* is sufficient for your purposes).

Hope it will help you or someone else facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that I've used when writing multi-purpose sub-tests which can be called from a test project [TestMethod()] is to Console.WriteLine messages within the sub-tests. These are not visible in the test results window, but you can see the console output (if any) in the "View Test Result Details" pane by right clicking on the individual test result.

> **Standard Console Output:** Hello there

Having no direct experience with your particular test scenario (Silverlight, or TFS) I'm not sure this is appliciple to SilverLight or not; but i hope this helps.